# MongoDB query to nested document returns nothing

Tags: mongodb

Here is a sample product document stored in MongoDB:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "....",
      "user_id": "....",
      "username": "....",
      // omitted
      "product": {
        "description": "A stunningly beautiful page with a constant growth of followers, etc. ❤",
        "banner_img": "https://tse3-mm.cn.bing.net/th/id/OIP.jNCbt_c_8vnq7sbWluCVnQHaCG?w=300&h=85&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7",
        "niches": "Fashion & Style",
        "categories": [
          {
            "type": "Single",
            "pricing": [
              {
                "time": 6,
                "price": 15,
                "bio_price": 10
              },
              {
                "time": 12,
                "price": 20,
                "bio_price": 10
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Multiple",
            "pricing": [
              {
                "time": 12,
                "price": 30.5,
                "bio_price": 15
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Story",
            "pricing": [
              {
                "time": 24,
                "price": 40,
                "bio_price": 20
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "created_at": "2020-01-11T18:19:54.312Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-11T18:19:54.312Z"
    }
  ],
```

I'd like to find an account that has a product with Multiple or Story pricing type. My query is as follows:

```
{
   product: {
     categories: {
       pricing: {
         $elemMatch: {
           type: { $in: ['Multiple', 'Story'] }
         }
       }

     }
   }
}
```

I'm running this query with `lucid-mongo` in adonisjs framework.
It should at least return one document but it returns nothing.
I ran the query both in framework and on mongo.exe but not works.
What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Are you sure that it returns nothing (https://mongoplayground.net/p/ouUcUw6sduz) ?

Comment: @mickl Thank you for suggesting nice mongodb sandbox!!!

Comment: So MongoDB does discriminate no quotes, single quotes and double quotes, which are perfectly tolerant in raw Javascript. Actually this query was made by myself using node.js How can I safely run query with this object? By json encode & decode?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem - your query is valid from node.js perspective. Could you edit your post and show how you run this query from node.js ?

Comment: I'm using lucid-mongo. It's like this: `const products = await Product.query().where(where).fetch()`. It's not working correctly, although mongodb query works well in mongoplayground. I logged query in console and it preserves single quotes in it. I think that's causing bugs.

Comment: @bravemaster : If it's still not working, maybe it's better to show your code, this query might not get what exactly you wanted but it should get something out !!

Comment: I've already found my errors. But @mickl's comment was very helpful. So I hope mickl to be my accepted answerer of this question.